geopandas.explore plot the wrong cordinates
I've been working on a georeferenced data set using geopandas library, when I use gdf.plot() the figure I get is right,in the sense that latitude and longitude of the POINTS being ploted match the background map.
enter image description here
But when I use de gdf.explore() method, the points appear squished around the latitude= 0.0, longitude =0.0 coordinates. if I zoom in enough I can see the distribution kind of match my original data.
enter image description here
I tried to check for NaN on the coordinates of my original data set but there are no problems there.

It's most likely a crs (projection) issue. Try to set it to EPSG:3857 or EPSG:4326. gdf.to_crs('epsg:3857').explore(). Or the geometry column is not defined properly with the right crs.

indeed it was, thanks

The problem that you encounter maybe it derives from the projection of your geodataframe. The explore() method uses the crs EPSG:4327
First you can check your crs(Coordinate Reference System) by using:

print(yourgeodataframe.crs)

Then change your crs of your data frame to EPSG:4326 by:

yourgeodataframe = yourgeodataframe.to_crs('EPSG:4326')

Finally try the explore() method again.
